# Convert array of objects into subarrays of objects by a selected property (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-manipulation

I am looking to take an array of objects, and convert it into an array of subarrays based on a chosen object property

for example:

```
[
  {foo: 1, bar: a}, {foo: 2, bar: b}, {foo: 1, bar: c}, {foo: 2, bar: d}
]
```

Create subarrays with the foo property would become:

```
[
  [
    {foo: 1, bar: a}, {foo: 1, bar: c}, 
  ],
  [
    {foo: 2, bar: b}, {foo: 2, bar: d}
  ]
]
```

I can't think of an efficient way to this. I keep resorting to creating a set of all of the unique property values of my chosen value, and then brute forcing through it multiple times.

```
const distinctProperties =  [...new Set(originalArray.map(item => item.foo))]

const newArray = distinctProperties.map(item => originalArray.filter(obj => obj.foo === item))
```

Thanks in advance for some advice here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can be done with `reduce`. you can wrap this around another function to group by the key you want.

Here I'm grouping based on the value of `foo` and `res` will be like this

```
{
  1: [{
  bar: "a",
  foo: 1
}, {
  bar: "c",
  foo: 1
}],
  2: [{
  bar: "b",
  foo: 2
}, {
  bar: "d",
  foo: 2
}]
}
```

then I'm taking `Object.values` of this to get the array format you want

```js
let a =[
  {foo: 1, bar: 'a'}, {foo: 2, bar: 'b'}, {foo: 1, bar: 'c'}, {foo: 2, bar: 'd'}
]

let res= Object.values(a.reduce((acc,curr)=> {
  if(!acc[curr.foo])acc[curr.foo]=[];
  acc[curr.foo].push(curr)
  return acc;
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

As a generalized function to take key name as input

```js
let a =[
  {foo: 1, bar: 'a'}, {foo: 2, bar: 'b'}, {foo: 1, bar: 'c'}, {foo: 2, bar: 'd'}
]


let groupByValue = (arr,key) => {
  return Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,curr)=> {
  if(!acc[curr[key]])acc[curr[key]]=[];
  acc[curr[key]].push(curr)
  return acc;
},{}))
}

let res1 = groupByValue(a,'foo')
let res2 = groupByValue(a,'bar')
console.log(res1)
console.log(res2)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much!